# i need to run a loop over a range of 140,000 rows

Tags: loops, resources, range, overflow

I need to run a loop over a range of 140K rows. I keep getting an overflow error. I tried just running the script over a range of 3,000 rows and it worked. I've tried a few things to conserve resources but nothing seems to work. is there a max range that you can work with? do yall have any tips for running a loop over this range?

example of what the code should do:
column6: (1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6)
----->
myarray1=(1,2,3,4,6)
column 1 has values all the way to row 140,000

```
Sub transferCC()

Dim i As Integer, counter1 As Integer
Dim x As String, y As String

Dim myarray1() As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Master")
Set ws1 = Sheets("CC List")

i = 2
counter1 = 0
x = "06331"

'save the unique CC values into myarray1
Do Until ws.Cells(i, 1) = ""
        x = ws.Cells(i, 6)
        y = ws.Cells(i + 1, 6) 'run-time error '6': overflow
            If x <> y Then
                ReDim Preserve myarray1(counter1)
                myarray1(counter1) = x
                Debug.Print myarray1(counter1)
                counter1 = counter1 + 1
            End If
i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you are receiving, and what line is throwing that error? Also, what version of VB are you using?

Comment: I don't see where you increment `i`, which should produce an infinite loop.

Comment: sorry about that, i had the increment in there but when excel froze it went back to the last saved copy. i should have QC'd that a bit more before posting.

Comment: Robert, the error message I get is run-time error '6': overflow and it throws the error when I try to set the value for y

Comment: it looks like the code saved up to 8 of the values in column 6. which would be on row 32562. then it throws the error...

Comment: so I can confirm that my script is stopping on row 32767. I tried deleting a few of the duplicate values above that row and reran the script. it still stopped on row 32767

Comment: Robert, I'm using VBA 7.1 in excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
It had nothing to do with the y variable.
it was stopping at row 32767 because that would be the value of i and i dim'd that as a int instead of long.
I did a little debug.print work and ended up searching for 32767 in google and found out that int variables can only go to 32767

thank you for trying everyone!